# How to run python script in atom in window 10

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor

[image]

Please help me to solve this my python file is in c:\python 3.6

Comment: I have installed both python and atom and I have installed the script package in atom..when I write program and run it..It say python is not recognised as internal or external command. So how i configure atom script to run my code inside atom??

Comment: Have you set `python.exe` to your `%PATH%`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

Firstly, you can add this on the top of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Secondly, for a more permanent solution, you can `python.exe` to your `%PATH%` variable. Go to `Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables`, select `PATH`, edit it, and add a new line pointing to the directory where Python resides.